# Как работает программа определения простоты числа?

Tags: java

В учебнике Шилдта встретил программу, пишет, простое число или нет, но не могу понять, как здесь работает isPrime.

```
int num;
boolean isPrime;
num = 9;
if(num < 2) isPrime = false;
else isPrime = true;
for(int i=2; i <= num/i;i++) {
if((num % i) == 0) { 
isPrime = false;
break;
}
}
if (isPrime) System.out.println("Простое");
else System.out.println("He простое");
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что именно вы не можете понять?

Answer (score 2):

Прочтите сначала что такое [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%F8%E5%F2%EE_%DD%F0%E0%F2%EE%F1%F4%E5%ED%E0) - по сути код как раз и реализует решето Эратосфена.

Comment: по сути, там реализована простая проверка деления числа на все числа предыдущие ему по порядку, если такое есть - число не простое, это решение - проверка по определению, не вижу я тут решета.

Comment: @Gorets ты невнимателен: обрати внимание на кусочек кода `for(int i=2; i <= num/i;i++)` - там цикл проходит не все числа :)

Comment: Этот код сильно ускоряется, если вместо i++ писать i+=2 и начать цикл с 3. Да, нужно проверить на делимость на два отдельно.